# HTML5 Canvas, shadowColor & shadowBlur

Tags: html, canvas

My question is regarding this shadowBlur feature used on the 2nd (outer) rectangle below. The shadowBlur feature is applied to every shape *after* this rectangle. (If you comment out the shadowColor and shadowBlur lines 21 & 22, and then uncomment the shadowColor and shadowBlur lines on lines 14 & 15, you should see what I mean.)  My question is, how do I apply shadowBlur to one specific portion of the Canvas drawing without applying the feature to every succeeding portion of the Canvas. In this example I have tried creating separate variable for each canvas and context, but the problem still persists.

Attribution: These examples are based on examples from html5canvastutorials.com

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRect(){
        var canvas1=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=canvas1.getContext("2d");

        var canvas3=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx3=canvas3.getContext("2d");

        ctx.rect(60,60,180,80);
        ctx.fillStyle="green";
        //ctx.shadowColor="black";
        //ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
        ctx.fill(); 


        ctx3.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx3.strokeStyle='red'; 
        ctx3.shadowColor="black";
        ctx3.shadowBlur = 10;       
        ctx3.strokeRect(45,45,210,110); 
    }

    function addOval(){
        var canvas2=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context=canvas2.getContext("2d");

        // define center of oval
        var centerX = 288;
        var centerY = 250;

        // define size of oval
        var height = 100;
        var width = 250;

        var controlRectWidth = width  * 1.33;

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(centerX,centerY - height/2);
        // draw left side of oval
        context.bezierCurveTo(centerX-controlRectWidth/2,centerY-height/2,
            centerX-controlRectWidth/2,centerY+height/2,
            centerX,centerY+height/2);

        // draw right side of oval
        context.bezierCurveTo(centerX+controlRectWidth/2,centerY+height/2,
            centerX+controlRectWidth/2,centerY-height/2,
            centerX,centerY-height/2);

        context.fillStyle="red";
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth=5;
        context.strokeStyle="blue"; 
        context.stroke();   
        context.closePath();    
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="addRect(); addOval();">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="400">
    Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use either this:

```
ctx.save();
  ctx.shadowColor="black";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10;       
  ctx.strokeRect(45,45,210,110); 
ctx.restore();
```

Or this:

```
ctx.shadowColor="black";
ctx.shadowBlur = 10;       
ctx.strokeRect(45,45,210,110); 
ctx.shadowColor= undefined; 
ctx.shadowBlur = undefined;
```

I am not sure about 'undefined' in second case - something to nullify/reset the value.

Comment: I changed 'unidentified' to 'null' and it worked like a charm. I also tried your other solution, and it worked as well. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

```
    var canvas3=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx3=canvas1.getContext("2d");
```

change canvas1 to canvas3 in the second line. Your ctx3 is actually pointing to canvas1 which i think is wrong.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks for that, but the problem still persists. I edited the question with your catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider setting the shadow color to "transparent" instead of undefined or null. This also seems to do the trick.