# HTML Shadow Attributes?

Tags: html, browser, css

Recently I found these strange HTML attributes in the wild:

```
<div shadowblur="1" shadowcolor="black" shadowopacity="0.5">
```

Any idea what browser this affects? Is it a good idea to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it affects the `<canvas>` tag:

[HTML5 Canvas, shadowColor & shadowBlur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286795/html5-canvas-shadowcolor-shadowblur)
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-example/

EDIT:

It definitely is for canvas in the form of `context.shadowBlur`

Comment: Why do you think this gets used instead of css box-shadow? Better performance maybe?

Comment: It's only used when you are drawing something in canvas. Box-shadow can be used on most css elements. Canvas tags, especially in this case, are not a substitute for CSS tags.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely working through css

This will help you to understand.

[CSS Attribute Selector: Apply class if custom attribute has value? Also, will it work in IE7+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416369/css-attribute-selector-apply-class-if-custom-attribute-has-value-also-will-it)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware those are not valid attributes. My guess is that they are used in a script to apply some effect. For example, a jQuery script could very easily iterate over all `div` elements and apply a set of CSS styles accordingly.

While that can work, a better idea would be to use HTML5 `data-*` attributes, otherwise your markup will not validate.