# HTML5 Canvas 2D Context -- How to reset the styles for the next drawing operation?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**So, I've got my cute little canvas context:**

```
var canvas    = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width  = 800;
canvas.height = 400;

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

**And I draw a line of text, with a shadow:**

```
context.textAlign = "center";
context.font      = "bold 20px sans-serif";
context.fillStyle = "#F90";

context.shadowColor   = "black";
context.shadowBlur    = 2;
context.shadowOffsetX = 2;
context.shadowOffsetY = 2;

context.fillText("Chivalry", canvas.width/2, 124);
```

**Later on, I go on to draw something else:**

```
context.textAlign = "center";
context.font      = "bold 16px sans-serif";
context.fillStyle = "white";

context.fillText("Medieval Warfare", canvas.width/2, 144);
```

**But I don't want that last one to have a shadow.** Of course, the context's shadow style properties were never reset, and so the shadow is applied to all further drawings.

### How should I restore the context's defaults?

Comment: Check out the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5286859/431287

Comment: You can wrap context state changes in `context.save ... context.restore`. But more efficient to turn shadowing off is rhino link that uses `context.shadowColor=null`.